# REDCap programming language for Data Quality checks

Tags: redcap

What is the programming language in REDCap for data quality checks and branching logic.
So far it's a bit hard to find the correct operators by trial and error.

It would be nice to know where to look for.

yesterday I programmed a data quality check which reads

```
([variable1] <> "" && [variable2] = "1")
```

It says that variable 1 should not be empty and variable 2 is also marked.

The code works, but it is though to find out how if I don't know the underlying language and the valid operators

Answer (score 1):

Information on the syntax and available operators and functions for data quality rule logic, branching logic, report filter logic, calculation expressions within REDCap is documented within REDCap itself on the "Help & FAQ" page. You can access that page either using the link towards the bottom of the left-hand menu column of a project page, or from the top nav bar of a non-project page (like My Projects).

In your check you should use `and` rather than `&&`:
`[variable1]<>'' and [variable2]='1'`

Comment: Dear Luke,

thanks for your reply. You are right the "Help & FAQ" page could have answerd my question if I would have read it more in depth. 

Why do you suggest to use rather ```and```  than ```&&``` ?

warmest

Comment: Because `and` is valid syntax for REDCap expressions and `&&` is not.